# Wrapfig changes indent of all subsequent itemize environments

Tags: indentation, itemize, wrapfig, parcolumns

I'm trying to fit a lot of information onto a single page, including bullets and a sidebar on the right (I don't care if the sidebar is the full length of the page or not). I understand that wrapfig and itemize don't work well together, but I haven't found anything but that works as well as wrapfig for the sidebar. Some environments can't handle the `\subsubsection*`. multicols doesn't do variable-width columns. vwcols is close, but it isn't even doing widths correctly at the moment and I don't want to invest time in it if I can get wrapfig to work. Any further ideas are welcome.

EDIT: Apparently I didn't read the vwcols documentation well enough. It's another one of the environments which doesn't handle sections/bullets well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.2\linewidth}

    \raggedright

    \vspace{-1.75em}
    \subsubsection*{Sidebar}
    \begin{hangparas}{1em}{1}
        A list

        A few of the items are long

        Other items aren't
    \end{hangparas}

\end{wrapfigure}

\section*{Main Document}

\subsection*{A Section}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Why does this fail?
\end{itemize}

\vspace{1cm}

\subsection*{Another Section}

\setlist{leftmargin=5mm}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Even after setting the left margin it still fails to indent appropriately
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \section and \subsection (anything using \@afterheading) should also be avoided using wrapfig.  In this case you just need to overlap the thingy on the right, not wrap text around it.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky bit was that `\smash` didn't like something inside the minipage, so I used a savebox.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}

    \raggedright

    \vspace{-1.75em}
    \subsubsection*{Sidebar}
    \begin{hangparas}{1em}{1}
        A list

        A few of the items are long

        Other items aren't
    \end{hangparas}

\end{minipage}}% something in here is incomplatible with \smash
\null\hfill\llap{\smash{\usebox\tempbox}}\par\vskip-\baselineskip

\section*{Main Document}

\subsection*{A Section}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Why does this fail?
\end{itemize}

\vspace{1cm}

\subsection*{Another Section}

\setlist{leftmargin=5mm}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Even after setting the left margin it still fails to indent appropriately
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OH I COMPLETELY FORGOT ABOUT MINIPAGE!
Thank you!

Comment: I also clearly need to learn about saveboxes. That seems like a very cool tool that I never heard about before.

Comment: Saveboxes are wonderful!  It doesn't quite convert anything into an image (otherwise \unvbox and \unhbox wouldn't work), but pretty much acts like it.  Plus it tells you the height, depth and width of whatever is inside.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by John Kormylo was very helpful, but long lines from the main page would write over the top of the sidebar. In the end, I just used a couple minipages.
[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.78\textwidth}

    \section*{Main Page}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Happily this will continue to work even when there's a very long line with lots of text
    \end{itemize}

    It also works... \hfill ...with hfill

    \subsection*{Another Section}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Some people might not like that this will continue to cause wrapping even below the sidebar. Sorry.
    \end{itemize}

\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}

    \raggedright

    \subsubsection*{Sidebar}
    \begin{hangparas}{1em}{1}
        A list

        A few of the items are long

        Other items aren't
    \end{hangparas}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```